# Getter/Setter from separate class file in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and for a HW assignment, we had to create a Person class that has a constructor, getter/setter for the attributes of firstName, lastName, phone.  That is in a separate file from an old HW assignment (Person.java).  Now we have to use that Person class in our new HW assignment (LoanApplication.java).  So if one of the attributes is

```
private Person client
```

do I need to create getter/setters or a constructor again?  Otherwise, how does each LoanApplicaiton instance know which Person attribute it is to go with?

How does the JVM know that it can use the Person.class even though my LoanApplicaiton.class does not extend Person.class?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, *assuming* that you wrote `class Person` in `Person.java` properly, you can just use it in `class LoanApplication` in `LoanApplication.java`. At this point, `Person.java` does not need to be modified, but you *do* have to make sure that the Java compiler can find it when you're compiling `LoanApplication.java`.

This means that you may have to add some `import` statements, or more simply, perhaps you just need to copy `Person.java` to the same homework directory as `LoanApplication.java`.

You do NOT have to `extends` an existing class to use it. A better way often is to *compose* instead of *inherit* (see: *Effective Java 2nd Edition*: Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance). For example, `Person.java` probably uses `String firstName`, etc. That means that `class Person` is composed using `String` (among other things), but it doesn't inherit from `String` (which is `final class` anyway).

---

> How does the JVM know that it can use the `Person.class` even though my `LoanApplication.class` does not extend `Person.class`?

This has nothing to do with inheritance. Even if `class LoanApplication extends Person` (which is a *HORRIBLE* idea, by the way),  the JVM would still need to be able to find `Person.class` to load `LoanApplication.class` (how JVM finds `.class` files, that's another issue entirely!)

Honestly, though, I don't think it's helpful to worry about details like this at this point. If you're serious about programming, I recommend getting an IDE such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/); it'd take care of the file management, linking, compilation, etc for you, so you can concentrate on the *real* task, which is *programming*.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to reimplement Person. Simply add the compiled "*.class" file to your classpath, and add the appropriate import statement in order to use instances of the Person class. This is, in fact, one of the benefits of object-oriented programming; old objects may be reused in new projects (assuming that they are well-designed and "do one thing and one thing well" and aren't coupled with application-specific logic).

I do not know what you mean by "how does each LoanApplicaiton instance know which Person attribute it is to go with", but assuming your getters/setters are public, then you can invoke those functions from your LoanApplication class. For example, if Person has a function called "setName()", you have a person instance in your loan application named "p", and a name "n", then you can call "p.setName(n)" to set p's name to n.

The Java Virtual Machine (JVM) has this concept called the "classpath" which determines where it looks for "*.jar" and "*.class" files, containing the definitions of various classes. The classes are saved in a format that the JVM is capable of reading and for taking their definitions. As for not extending it... there are several different ways that objects can interact in an object-oriented programming language; inheritance (one object extends another), polymorphism (multiple different classes provide different implementations for the same interface... this is a particular application of inheritance), composition (a class is composed of instances of other classes), delegation (one class delegates its work to one or more instances of other classes, which is a special case of composition), among many other OOP design patterns. In this case, you need composition.